# C# Tuition Discount How to compute discount

Tags: c#

Example if Tuition Fee is : 3000

Discount Percent in Cash : 20%
                   Installment : 5%

Total : (here)

**Code**

```
int tuition = 0; 
double cash = 0.20; 
double installment = 0.5; 
double discount; double total;

tuition = int.Parse(textBox4.Text); 
cash = double.Parse(textBox1.Text); 

//Computation
discount = tuition * (cash / 100); 
discount = tuition * installment; 
total = tuition - discount; 

textBox5.Text = discount.ToString(); 
textBox3.Text = total.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer :D

Comment: Heres my Current Code :

            int tuition = 0;
            double cash = 0.20;
            double installment = 0.5;
            double discount;
            double total;

            tuition = int.Parse(textBox4.Text);

            cash = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);

           
            discount = tuition * (cash / 100);
            discount = tuition * installment;

            total = tuition - discount;

            textBox5.Text = discount.ToString();
            textBox3.Text = total.ToString();

Comment: Post your code into question, please.

Comment: There Posted, thanks for the help

Comment: always input is 1500, but it should be 600.

Comment: Can you post the mathematical formular?

Comment: if cash = 3000 * 0.20 if installment 3000 * 0.5

Comment: still need answer -_-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seperate the two discounts into seperate variables and compute to get the right results:

```
//Computation
var cashDiscount = tuition * (cash / 100); 
var installationDiscount = tuition * installment; 
discount = cashDiscount + installationDiscount;
total = tuition - discount; 

textBox5.Text = discount.ToString(); 
textBox3.Text = total.ToString();
```